# Design/Theory: How to have default value for multiple users?

Tags: database

I have a users table. Then a product types table, and each user can input/edit/delete their own product typess. They can only see their own product typess.

But I want everyone to have a default 'unknown' product type, that can not ever be deleted.

I figure I see 2 ways to do this.

1) make the first row of the product type table 'unknown' and then have that return for every user. But write queries that never let you delete row 1.

2) add an 'unknown' row at the time of each user creation, and add a 'deleteable' column that flags it. And then check for that on each deletion.

Option 1 makes a LOT more sense in my mind for some reason.  Is it an okay way to do this? Or is option 2 better from a design aspect?

Thanks

edit:
clarified there is only a users table and a product types table. And I want everyone to have a default product type of 'unknown'

Comment: What, if any, is the difference between a *product type* and a *product*?  Which does each row of your table represent?

Comment: @ScottHunter sorry that was not as clear as i should have made it. I updated it a bit. Each row of the product type table represents a product type. And I want everyone to have a default product type of 'unknown'. There actually is no products table.

Comment: Would allowing `NULL` as a product type do the job?

Comment: @ScottHunter Not with my current setup, I guess I could change things to make Null work. But in the future I may do that. Its more of a question about 1 vs 2, but yeah maybe I should have added a 3rd option of just leave things as null.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't have users deleting each other's `ProductTypes`, your `ProductTypes` table must currently look like:

```
ProductTypeId | Name | OwnedByUserId
```

In that case, I'd be inclined to do a small variant on Option #1: create a `UserId = 0` as a "system" | "default" | "shared" user, and have them own the "unknown" ProductType. You get the delete protection for free (since it's another user), but do still need to union when retrieving.

If you want to add other defaults later, then you just make them owned by the "default" user.

If you want to switch to option #2 later (perhaps you want them to be able to delete now), you can use the "default" user as a template and easily backfill the existing users.

Comment: I do have an OwnedByUserId type of column. So yeah this could work. A default user with the 'default' rows for each table. And then unions elsewhere when I need to let them choose the default column. I'll look more at doing it like that. Thanks

Comment: Use union all instead of Union because there will not be a need to check for duplicates as the data is mutually exclusive.